# Filter options in one to one field django admin

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-admin

I have this 2 models

```
from django.db import models

def get_upload_path(instance, filename):
    return '{0}/{1}'.format(instance.imovel.id, filename)

# Create your models here.
class Imovel(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    descricao = models.CharField(max_length=800)
    area = models.IntegerField()
    quartos = models.SmallIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    banheiros = models.SmallIntegerField()
    disponivel_aluguel = models.BooleanField()
    disponivel_venda = models.BooleanField()
    valor_aluguel = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2)
    valor_venda = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2)
    valor_condominio = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2)
    valor_iptu = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2)
    capa = models.OneToOneField('ImagemImovel', related_name='capa', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'imovel'

class ImagemImovel(models.Model):
    imovel = models.ForeignKey(Imovel, related_name='imagens', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    nomeImagem = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    imagem = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_upload_path)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nomeImagem

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'imagemImovel'
```

I have houses and it's pictures and a field named 'capa' to say which one is the main picture.
The problem is when I add a house through django admin, save and come back to choose the main one it let me choose images from other houses. How could I filter it to just show images that are related to this specific house?

My django admin file

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import ImagemImovel, Imovel

# Register your models here.
class ImagemImovelAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = ImagemImovel

class ImovelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (ImagemImovelAdmin, )

admin.site.register(Imovel, ImovelAdmin)
```

Comment: I do not fully understand. In the current setting, you should be able to see the associated images when you click the Imovel model in the admin panel. Can you explain more in detail?

Comment: When I'm in admin panel I can add a  house and the images of this house in the same place due to "inlines = (ImagemImovelAdmin, )" in my admin.py, what i want is to filter the options in field 'capa'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my ImovelAdmin class so I can get the id from the model using the get_form function and use it in a filter for the queryset

```
class ImovelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        inlines = (ImagemImovelAdmin, )
        id_for_formfield = None
        def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
            if obj:
                self.id_for_formfield = obj.id
            return super(ImovelAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
            if db_field.name == "capa" and self.id_for_formfield is not None:
                kwargs["queryset"] = ImagemImovel.objects.filter(imovel=self.id_for_formfield)
            return super(ImovelAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
    
    admin.site.register(Imovel, ImovelAdmin)
```